# How to solve typescript errors: This condition will always return 'false' since the types have no overlap when I have 3 conditional renderings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I have in my jsx code 3 conditional checks depending on const role which now is hardcoded but later on will have dynamic value. It might have 3 values: "GUEST", "HR", "ADMIN" and depending on the const role value particular List component for Drawer from MUI should be rendered. But when I add those 3 conditions to the code and hover over "HR" or "ADMIN" I get the comment that This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"GUEST"' and '"ADMIN"' have no overlap.ts(2367)

```
const role = 'GUEST';
 <Drawer
              anchor="left"
              open={showMenu}
              onClose={toggleMenu}
              PaperProps={{
                sx: {
                  width: '250px',
                },
              }}
            >
              {role === 'GUEST' && (
                <List>
                  <HeaderLinkItem
                    icon={LoginIcon}
                    link="/login"
                    label="Login"
                    onClick={toggleMenu}
                  />
                </List>
              )}
              {role === 'HR' && (
                <List>
                  <HeaderLinkItem
                    icon={DashboardIcon}
                    link="/dashboard"
                    label="Dashboard"
                    onClick={toggleMenu}
                  />
                  <HeaderLinkItem
                    icon={ListAltIcon}
                    link="/employees"
                    label="Employees"
                    onClick={toggleMenu}
                  />
                  <HeaderLinkItem
                    icon={ListAltIcon}
                    link="/candidates"
                    label="Candidates"
                    onClick={toggleMenu}
                  />
                  <HeaderLinkItem
                    icon={PostAddIcon}
                    link="/candidates/create"
                    label="New candidate"
                    onClick={toggleMenu}
                  />
                </List>
              )}
              {role === 'ADMIN' && (
                <List>
                  <HeaderLinkItem
                    icon={DashboardIcon}
                    link="/dashboard"
                    label="Dashboard"
                    onClick={toggleMenu}
                  />
                  <HeaderLinkItem
                    icon={ListAltIcon}
                    link="/employees"
                    label="Employees"
                    onClick={toggleMenu}
                  />
                  <HeaderLinkItem
                    icon={ListAltIcon}
                    link="/candidates"
                    label="Candidates"
                    onClick={toggleMenu}
                  />
                  <HeaderLinkItem
                    icon={PostAddIcon}
                    link="/candidates/create"
                    label="New candidate"
                    onClick={toggleMenu}
                  />
                  <HeaderLinkItem
                    icon={AdminPanelSettingsIcon}
                    link="/admin"
                    label="Admin Panel"
                    onClick={toggleMenu}
                  />
                </List>
              )}
</Drawer>
```

Can You please suggest how to fix it ?

thanks

Comment: You're hardcoding GUEST so the other two will never be true. Don't hardcode.

Comment: Marcinb, I suspect that the comment "This condition will always return 'false'" is being shown by your editor/IDE (e.g. VS Code). Such a comment is *correct* because the code is hardcoded *at this moment*. It is being shown based on static code analysis. As soon as you replace the hardcoded value with something else, the comment will obviously no longer appear. - If this does not answer your question, then please [edit] the question and make it more clear what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it like this (note `string` type). By default, the type of role is not string, it is 'GUEST' (a constant string that may have only one value):

```
const role: string = 'GUEST';
```